# Catching ASP.Net MVC Principle Permission attribute exceptions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, permissions, action-filter

I would like to secure my MVC controller actions using...

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role="Administrator")]
```

However, if the user is not in this role then a SecurityException "Request for principal permission failed." is thrown by the code.

There seems to be no way to handle this error, even [Handle] error wont catch it.

What I would like is a way to catch the security exceptions and then redirect the user to my Login page (or route).

Or, some way to write my own action filter that I can add to any method e.g.

```
[MustBeAnAdministrator]
```

... which would check if the user is in the correct role, and redirect them. However, I cant seem to get a redirection to work in an action filter.

Thanks.

Comment: If your Role is a Windows group then you probably mean 'Administrators' with a 's'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our MVC-project we use the

```
<Authorize(Roles:="Administrators")>
```

Function given by the MembershipProvider - which we fitted to our conditions. If the user is not logged in he will be forwarded to the login-screen.